# Set default application for text files via SFTP

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, files, default-programs, sftp

When I double-click a plain text file with no file extension on my local hard drive, it is opened in Emacs as I probably once chose Emacs as the default application to open this kind of file in the `Open With` tab of the dialog shown when you right-click a file in Nautilus and then choose `Properties`. This seems like quite a reasonable choice as Emacs is a text editor.

If, however, I connect to a serve via SFTP in Nautilus and want to open a text file on that server by double-clicking it, VLC is opened. This seems completely unreasonable as one can neither view nor edit text files with VLC.

I can choose to open the file in GEdit or Atom in the context menu, but Emacs isn't provided as an option:

[image]

This particular file contains the text

```
This is a Borg repository
```

which is 25 characters long and then a line feed. As you can see in the screenshot, its size is 26 Byte, so there can't be any weird data in it which would possibly be confused with the magic number of any video format. In fact, this is its content according to Bless Hex Editor:

```
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 42 6F 72 67 20 72 65 70 6F 73 69 74 6F 72 79 0A
```

When I right-click the file and choose `Properties`, there is no `Open With` tab:

[image]

How do I make Nautilus (3.14.3) open text via SFTP in Emacs / use my default application for local files?

Comment: Try looking into your systemsettings -> details, what default applications are set. Maybe you'll find there already the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce. File mimetypes are detected correctly for me. 16.04/nautilus, 3.14.3.

Comment: @Ziazis This only has the kinds of files "Web", "Mail", "Calendar", "Music", "Video", and "Photos". Nothing about text files. VLC only was in there once ("Video") and I now changed that to mpv. Still, text files via SFTP are attempted to be opened using VLC.

Comment: @muru Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a different machine and now checked how it behaves in this regard. It didn't open the file at all at first but told me to select an application. After choosing GEdit, the text file was opened in GEdit and was opened in GEdit right when double-clicking the file subsequently. I suppose this behavior depends on what was first selected but don't know how to undo this selection. There isn't an `Open With` tab on the new installation either, when on an SFTP resource.

Comment: @UTF-8 the system you're SFTPing to, what is it?

Comment: @muru In both cases my Raspberry Pi. I even used the very same file to check the behavior of the new system. My raspi runs Ubuntu 16.04 MATE.